# 2 functions same time jQuery slideUp -slideDown + resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What's the best solution to run those functions at the same time?

Mainly: slideDown and fancybox.resize, as it's now run on function complete, function fancybox.resize has to be run **while** slidedown is running, otherwise it won't work.

```
function DisplayLogin() {
    jQuery("#sign-up-select").slideUp(400);
    jQuery("#login-select").slideDown(400, function(){
        jQuery.fancybox.resize()
    });
}
```

Thanks!!
Adam

Thanks for help guys!!

That's what I wanted to get - final result:

```
function DisplayLogin() {
    jQuery("#sign-up-select").slideUp(400);
    jQuery("#login-select").slideDown(400);
    var interval = setInterval(function(){jQuery.fancybox.resize()}, 100);  
    setTimeout(function() {
            clearInterval(interval);
        }, 400);
}
```

Comment: take it out of the complete callback maybe?

Comment: make a fiddle so we can see all of your code and play with it

Comment: without callback it's gonna resize it when slideDown is in progress.

Comment: @AdamLesniak is that not exactly what you asked for? *"function fancybox.resize has to be run when slidedown is running, otherwise it won't work."* while it is in progress would be while it is running.

Comment: @KevinB you're right Kevin, my mistake, sorry! fixed up my post

Answer (score 1):

Run another function while other is 'running' using setInterval.

```
function DisplayLogin() {
    jQuery("#sign-up-select").slideUp(400);
    jQuery("#login-select").slideDown(400);
    var interval = setInterval(function(){jQuery.fancybox.resize()}, 100);  
    setTimeout(function() {
            clearInterval(interval);
        }, 400);
}
```